# Python 2.7 sklearn.svm warning message

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, regression, svm

I am running a Support Vector Regression in Python using:

```
model=SVR(C=1.0, epsilon=0.01,kernel='linear',verbose=True)
```

I received the following warning:

```
[LibSVM].........................................
Warning: using -h 0 may be faster
```

What does it mean? How can I use this information?

Comment: What is the version of your sklearn? Are you using a development version?

Comment: Yes, '0.20.dev0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70242/libsvm-warning-using-h-0-may-be-faster):

> This means, that optimization algorithm detected that with high probability (not in the strict, mathematical sense) you can speed up your training by turning the -h 0 flag in your options. Basically, -h is the shrinking heuristics, implemented in the libsvm package which for some data significantly reduces number of required computations, while in others - makes it slower.

This flag is implemented in sklearn with 'shrinking' parameter which you can set to `False` (shrinking=False)